Inside the box: A decade!
On your desk, where you divide ideas into right and wrong, devise or reject approaches, there's a box, and on it a note made of kami. It says:
"Here's your present! Inside the box is a decade!
But not just any decade: This decade has all the right stuff: three of the best years you'll ever see!
One's just in the past, one's right around the corner, and one's not too long after that.
It's very rare to have a decade this quaternarily regular: we haven't had an opportunity like this in over 500 years! But prepackaged fact or not, it's not as rare as all that: There'll be another decade to match this one in under 100 years.
Nonetheless, enjoy your rightful present!"
What are the three special years in the decade?


 Bonus: how many puns and references can you find?


@msh210 The phrasing "made of kami" is intentional. The note is made of a material called "kami".

@bobble Sure, I added it

Perhaps the 'kami' the note is made of is referring to this?
